# Why isn't findAll returning the expected number of divs from a web page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm learning how to web scrape and on a tutorial I'm following the inspect option displays the code of some web page, and in the tutorial from 2017 the info he needed was listed under " div class = "item-container "and when he used the findAll function it returned to him the number of divs it found with that class and name. When I inspect it today, the relevant div is called "div class = "item-inner", however when I run it, it tells me that the findAll function found zero items with those parameters even though I see the div listed in the html when I inspect it and am definitely not mistyping.

Comment: please provide the code where you're having this issue

Comment: To get help you need to present sample html and python a block of code you have tried.